# Should I use the latest version of jQuery or the one that comes with the jQuery UI package?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The latest version of jQuery currently is 1.10.2 and for jQuery UI it's 1.10.3, but the jQuery UI bundle comes with the jQuery 1.9.1.

My questions are:

1. Shall I use jQuery 1.10.2 or 1.9.1 in my project?
2. Is there any specific reason that jQuery UI package comes with jQuery 1.9.1 instead of jQuery 1.10.2?

Comment: It's worth noting that `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` are actually different libraries, developed by different teams, with different release cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery UI comes with jQuery 1.9.1 simply because on May 3, 2013 when the latest version of UI was released the latest version of jQuery was 1.9.1.

You should always use the latest version unless you have a specific reason not to.